# How to validate date inputs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, date, object

I'm building a date picker React component, where a user can type the day, month, year or select it from a calendar.

I'm being lazy and seeing if the date is valid for the text input by using:

```
  validateDate(event) {
    const { selectedDay, selectedMonth, selectedYear } = this.state;
    const checkDateIsValid = new Date(
      selectedMonth.toString() + '/' +
      selectedDay.toString() + '/' +
      selectedYear.toString());
    if (checkDateIsValid == 'Invalid Date') {
      this.setState({ validDate: false });
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ validDate: true });
    }
 }
```

However, there's a issue where an invalid date of the 31st of February will create a valid Date object of '3rd March...'. I know I can get input validation by manually comparing the day and month field to see if you can have valid matches, but I'm wondering if there is a quicker way of doing that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) to check whether the date is valid or not. I don't know why you are splitting date and joining. But it will helps you!

```
var date = moment(YOUR_DATE_STRING);  // For example --> moment('2017-11-22')
if(date.isValid()) {
  this.setState({ validDate: true });
}
else {
   this.setState({ validDate: false });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like I wanted it to. Im joining the string as the input consists of separate day,month,year boxes

Comment: @user3187956 - Yes that may be your situation to do like that. If answer suits for you please accept.